# Different sockets

Tags: java, networking, java-io

Is there anyway that you can use 2 different sockets that connect to the same IP and port and have them do different jobs e.g this socket used for chatting, the other is used for sending file.

Comment: Sure, but each socket will have to tell the server what it wants to be used for.

Comment: You may be trying to send an attachment through chat, if so then just change your message format from simple string to object/json/xml and use metadata data fields which indicate what type of message it is and in the message body send the actual message.

Comment: Does that mean I have to initialize 2 serverSocket in the server side?